# converting individual dictonary to list of dictonary and iterating over it

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary, stock

I am working with nsepython library where i want to iterate over each openInterest key and check for the top 3 values for that key and print the strike price ,OI, Volume, changeinopenInterest.
But when I extract data for particular script it gives me seperate dictonary for each strike price and i am not able to iterate over it.

```
{
  "strikePrice": 2400,
  "expiryDate": "27-May-2021",
  "underlying": "TCS",
  "identifier": "OPTSTKTCS27-05-2021CE2400.00",
  "openInterest": 1,
  "changeinOpenInterest": 0,
  "pchangeinOpenInterest": 0,
  "totalTradedVolume": 0,
  "impliedVolatility": 0,
  "lastPrice": 0,
  "change": 0,
  "pChange": 0,
  "totalBuyQuantity": 5700,
  "totalSellQuantity": 11400,
  "bidQty": 5700,
  "bidprice": 635.75,
  "askQty": 11400,
  "askPrice": 785.45,
  "underlyingValue": 3077.3
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code used to get the dictionary data?

Comment: `from nsepython import*
from pprint import pprint
from nsepython import*
print(option_chain("TCS"))`

Comment: Ok. Not all records seem to contain a value for `PE`, how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to receive a full list of strike prices with version `0.0.94` of nsepython:

```py
>>> import nsepython
>>> c = nsepython.option_chain('TCS')
>>> interests = [(rec.get('PE', {'openInterest': 0})['openInterest'], rec.get('PE', {'strikePrice': 0})['strikePrice'], rec.get('PE', {'totalTradedVolume': 0})['totalTradedVolume'], rec.get('PE', {'changeinOpenInterest': 0})['changeinOpenInterest']) for rec in c['records']['data']]
>>> interests.sort(reverse=True)  # sort by changeinOpenInterest
>>> interests[:3]  # get top 3 of (openInterest, strikePrice, totalTradedVolume, changeinOpenInterest)
[(1115, 3000, 1399, 18), (599, 3100, 1704, 12), (560, 2800, 156, -4)]
```